# Need to change which view gets displayed on start up

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a Xcode project using the tabbed application template. Currently, when the app is started, it immediately switches to the First View Controller.  I would like to change it to go to the Second View Controller instead. I've looked at the Tab Bar Controller for attributes.  The only thing I see is under the Connections inspector/Trigger Segues/view controllers shows a list of View Controllers (First, Second, Third).  Does anyone know how to change the automatic switch?  iOS 8/Xcode 6.1

Comment: Why don't you switch the order of the controllers in the tabs? A tab bar controller always starts by presenting the controller in the first tab.

Comment: Where do I do that?  I've looked at the tab controller.  The Triggered Seques list the 3 tabs that this tab controller calls.  The default goes to "First".  I want it to go to "Locations" by default.  Is it possible that I have to delete "First" and then re-add it?

Comment: Yes, just delete the connections between the tab bar controller and its children. Remake them by control dragging. Remake them in the order you want them to appear.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

Firstly, there's an arrow at the left of the Initial View Controller. You can drag this arrow to any other view controller and that will become the initial controller.

Secondly, you can click on the view controller, go to the Metrics tab in the inspector (the one with the downward pointing thing) and then check the option that says "Is Initial View Controller".

Comment: I think the OP still wants the tab bar controller to be the initial view controller - just wants a different tab selected by default.

Comment: Thank you, guys.  But I really do want to keep the tab controller.  I just want to switch around which view controller gets called by default.  And I'm just not seeing it.  (See my comment above)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is:  Delete the First connection listed under the identity inspector and then re-add it.  This bumps the second one up to the first place and positions it where I want it.